# Three level eloquent relation orderBy in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

In my database, I have the following tables:

```
quotes
-id
-quote_title
...

quote_items
-id
-quote_id
-product_id

products
-id
-product_name
-product_category_d
```

What I want to achieve is to sort the result of my query using product_category_id.

Below is the query.

```
$query = Quote::query();
$query->whereHas('quote_item' , function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('product' , function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('product_category_id');
    });
 });
$temp= $query->find($id);
```

The result doesn't show any errors but isn't in order.

Quote Model :

```
class Quote extends Model
{
    public function QuoteItem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\QuoteItem');
    }
}
```

QuoteItem Model:

```
class QuoteItem extends Model
{
    public function Quote()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Quote');
    }

    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Product');
    }
}
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function QuoteItem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\QuoteItem');
    }

}
```

Comment: Please specify why to order by product.category_id? If quote has many quote_items what is the priority of product categories order?

Comment: A quote can have multiples products, which one do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes of course

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating dedicated scope for `Quote` model:

```php
public function scopeOrderByCategory($query)
{
    return $query
        ->join('quote_items', 'quote_items.quote_id', '=', 'quotes.id')
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'quote_items.product_id')
        ->orderBy('products.product_category_id');
}
```

Then you can use it whenever you are selecting quotes and need to order them by their product's category:

```php
$quotes = Quote::orderByCategory()->get();
```

But you will have to be cautious about the fact that this scope inner joins `quote_items` and `products` tables.

You can read more on local Eloquent scopes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes).

Comment: when I use this command show me null `print_r(quotes->quoteitem )`  . in quote model  I have `public function Quoteitem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('appl\Quoteitem');
    }`

Comment: @paranoid we will have to ask you to provide more context since I don't quite understand. Where do you do this "command", what's in `$quotes`? Also, by the looks of it, you don't follow Laravel's naming convention in terms of tables, relations and models names, so you need to explain that too. What is `Quoteitem`? Is it a model for `products` table or for `quote_items`? Because you might have your relationships set up wrong.

Comment: When I use this `Quote::orderByCategory()->find($id);` result of `print_r(quotes->quoteitem )` is null but when remove `orderByCategory()` show all of quoteitems

Comment: @paranoid inner joins in the scope I provided will leave only quotes that have existing products related to them via your pivot `quote_items` table. Meaning that you probably don't have products attached properly. In fact, you should've used `belongsToMany` relationship between quotes and products with `quote_items` being it's pivot table (you don't need to create separate model and relationships for it). Go check your data in DB once again, if those joins doesn't return rows then your quotes are not in the relation with products via `quote_items` (related `quote_items` have null `product_id`)

Answer (score -2):

if you look closely in your query, the order by was put in the `whereHas` clause. I think it should be put in the `with` clause

I modified the query like this.

```
$results = Quote::with(['QuoteItem' => function ($query) {
                            $query->join('products', 'products.id', 
                                         '=', 'quote_items.product_id')
                                  ->orderBy('product_category_id','ASC');
                        }])->whereHas('QuoteItem')->find($id);
```

Results shown using `dd()` function of Laravel:
[image]

Comment: I think this is a long query to execute .. it's proper to make join query then order what you want !!

Comment: @MohamedEmad yes it is also another way for him to get his desired results but maybe, he wants to maximize the eloquent functionality of laravel instead of using query builder in this matter.

Comment: @MohamedEmad `product_category_id` is on product table not `quote_item` table

Comment: @MohamedEmad I tested it but not work correctly my query similar to  your query but it dose not work correctly

Comment: @IndianCoding I want to sort products not qoute. I have one quote, because I use `find` method

Comment: @paranoid The previous code wasn't able to deliver the desired results because it only sort all the products inside the quote_items which has a one to one relationship to products table. I edited the code and use eloquent and join function using query builder. This is one way to address your problem. I also tested it :).